# Scraping function for Transfermarket

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a function that will go into a team Transfermarket page and will bring me all the data from the table in this [Page](https://www.transfermarkt.es/sport-club-corinthians-paulista/kader/verein/199/saison_id/2011/plus/1) for each year.

The problems I am having are 2.

1. Index number 13 which is the market_value is saying index it is out of range but if you print the length of print('column:', len(all_td)) you get 13 which is the las column.
2. I am getting quintuplicad result or more times than 5 the same player I know I can do a drop_duplicates but don´t want to do it.

I am new in this field and this is for my course and I am stuck at here.

Thanks for the help.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

data_CORIN = {
'name': [],
'field_position': [],
'date_of_birth': [],
'height': [],
'foot': [],
'market_value': [],
'anio': []
}

headers = {
   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
  Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

l = [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]

for i in range(0,len(l)-1):
  url = "https://www.transfermarkt.es/sport-club-corinthians-paulista/kader/verein/199/saison_id/{}/plus/1".format(l[i])
  response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

all_tr = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': ['odd', 'even']}, recursive=True)
print('rows:', len(all_tr))

  for row in all_tr:
  all_td = row.find_all('td', recursive=True)
  print('columns:', len(all_td))
  
   for column in all_td:
    print(' >', column.text)

  data_CORIN['name'].append( all_td[3].text.split('.')[0][:15])
  data_CORIN['field_position'].append( all_td[4].text)
  data_CORIN['date_of_birth'].append( all_td[5].text[12:14])
  data_CORIN['height'].append( all_td[8].text )
  data_CORIN['foot'].append( all_td[9].text )
  data_CORIN['market_value'].append( all_td[12].text )
  data_CORIN['anio'].append(l[i]) 

df = pd.DataFrame(data_CORIN)
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will go from year 2011 to 2020 and save all details to `data.csv` file:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

all_data = []
for year in range(2011, 2021):
    print('Getting data for year {}..'.format(year))

    url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.es/sport-club-corinthians-paulista/kader/verein/199/plus/1/galerie/0?saison_id=' + str(year)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

    th = soup.select('.items th')
    if len(th) == 11:
        for td in soup.select('.items > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(5)'):
            td.extract()

    for tr in soup.select('.items > tbody > tr:has(td)'):
        name = tr.select_one('a[id]').get_text(strip=True)
        field_position = tr.select_one('table > tr:nth-child(2)').text

        dob = tr.select_one('td:nth-child(3)').text
        height = tr.select_one('td:nth-child(5)').text
        foot = tr.select_one('td:nth-child(6)').text
        mv = tr.select_one('td:nth-child(10)').text

        all_data.append({
            'Name': name,
            'Field Position': field_position,
            'Height': height,
            'Date of Birth': dob,
            'Foot': foot,
            'Market Value': mv,
            'Year': year
        })

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Prints:

```
Getting data for year 2011..
Getting data for year 2012..
Getting data for year 2013..
Getting data for year 2014..
Getting data for year 2015..
Getting data for year 2016..
Getting data for year 2017..
Getting data for year 2018..
Getting data for year 2019..
Getting data for year 2020..
                 Name    Field Position  Height    Date of Birth       Foot    Market Value  Year
0         Júlio César           Portero  1,85 m  27/10/1984 (26)  izquierdo  2,50 mill. €    2011
1              Cássio           Portero  1,95 m  06/06/1987 (24)    derecho  1,00 mill. €    2011
2    Danilo Fernandes           Portero  1,89 m  03/04/1988 (23)    derecho   200 miles €    2011
3     Matheus Vidotto           Portero  1,89 m  10/04/1993 (18)    derecho   100 miles €    2011
4      Leandro Castán   Defensa central  1,86 m  05/11/1986 (24)  izquierdo  2,50 mill. €    2011
..                ...               ...     ...              ...        ...             ...   ...
424   Gabriel Pereira   Extremo derecho  1,75 m  01/08/2001 (18)  izquierdo   675 miles €    2020
425              Luan        Mediapunta  1,80 m  27/03/1993 (27)    derecho  6,50 mill. €    2020
426                Jô  Delantero centro  1,92 m  20/03/1987 (33)  izquierdo  2,50 mill. €    2020
427     Mauro Boselli  Delantero centro  1,85 m  22/05/1985 (35)    derecho  1,20 mill. €    2020
428         Carlinhos  Delantero centro  1,95 m  12/02/1997 (23)    derecho    50 miles €    2020

[429 rows x 7 columns]
```

Produces this CSV (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still having issues looks like Beautiful Soup does not recognize

nth-child

Getting data for year 2011..
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
raceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-b6b3767adec0> in <module>()
     16     th = soup.select('.items th')
     17     if len(th) == 11:
---> 18         for td in soup.select('.items > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(5)'):
     19             td.extract()
     20 

NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: @MartinTesta That means you're using old version of `beautifulsoup`. Upgrade BeautifulSoup to the latest version.

Comment: It worked the problem is Colab that does not updates the latest version in JupyterLabs worked thanks so much !